# Inconsistent arrow graphics between a beta site and its meta

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, user-interface, beta-phase

On the left side, beta icons for the gaming site; on the right side, beta icons for gaming meta site.

[icons for gaming beta http://img810.imageshack.us/img810/7828/spritesp.png](http://img810.imageshack.us/img810/7828/spritesp.png) [icons for meta of gaming beta http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/5165/spriteso.png](http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/5165/spriteso.png)

The two are nearly identical except for some minor variations... including the up/down arrows, which are a bit confusing. A clicked arrow in meta is a non-clicked arrow in the regular site. Maybe one of them could be altered a bit? Or better yet, maybe they should be merged?

**EDIT:** to clarify - I don't have a problem with the icons being different, only with the up/down arrows (hence the question title). As I participate in the beta I hop a lot between the actual site and its meta, and its confusing that a marked arrow on one site is an unmarked arrow on another.

I'm posting this here and not in the gaming meta site because I guess this affects all beta sites.

Comment: Is the glowing check mark still in use? I thought they removed that with the new bounty system.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is with this colour scheme at all. It's perfectly clear to me.

Comment: Technically, they're not really the same. The shading on the inactive arrows on the parent site is a light grey, whilst the active arrows on the meta site are a black. It looks 50/50 on the light grey, so I'm thinking it's not a subtle difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is by design. The design goal is to differentiate a normal arrow from its highlighted state. On the regular site, we use a highlighter effect. Since on Meta the color scheme is mostly monochromatic, we went with hollow vs filled look. The overall shape of the arrows between regular site and meta site are the same, so I don't think most people have to relearn the UI familiarity.

Comment: What kind of authority do you have?? `:P`

Comment: @Justin - you are joking aren't you? http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/our-designer-in-residence-jin-yang/

Comment: @ChrisF I sure am joking.  That's what the `:P` means.  I do understand that it is better to be safe than sorry though.

Comment: I still think the arrows should be changed - I get confused all the time - but thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Justin - I didn't register the ":P" at first, but I thought I ought to post the link just in case...

Answer (score 2):

This is by convention that all the meta sites are literally gray areas. Removing almost all the colour from the icons is done to indicate a visual difference in the sites, while still maintaining an obvious relationship (that you aren't on a *completely* foreign website).

I think this is a good practice.

Comment: I don't mind that the icons are different; I just find the up-down arrows thing confusing.

Comment: If your question is about specific icons, then you should limit your screenshot to only the icons you are concerned with.

Comment: It's not a screenshot :) it's just the image of all icons. I've edited my question to clarify.